# Threading in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Is it possible to do threading in Google Apps Script? Currently I am setting up triggers programmatically to do threading. Is there a better way?

Comment: About thread is an enhancement and are investigating possible solutions. [Issue 1973: Add support for long-running tasks](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1973) and [Issue 2992: Multi Threading](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2992)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a great example from Bruce Mcphearson.  His example [Parallel Processing in Apps Script](https://ramblings.mcpher.com/parallel-processing-in-apps-script/) uses Map Reduce in exercise.  He is utilizing triggers as well, but perhaps may provide some different perspective.